# Add a label to a table while using \input{}

Tags: cross-referencing, input

I have tables saved as separate .tex files and am using them as input files when compiling my main document. I was wondering if there was a way that I could label my tables as I input them rather than having to edit each .tex file.

So something like:

```
\input{file_1.tex}\label{tab:file_1_table}

Table \ref{tab:file_1_table} depicts ...
```

I had seen another post where someone tried this:

```
\newcommand\labelthistable{\label{tab:file_1_table}}\input{file_1.tex}
```

But that doesn't exactly work.

Here is an example of the contents of those input files:

```
\begin{table}

\caption{Listwise Deletion Versus Amelia}
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t]{lc}
\toprule
  & Model 1\\
\midrule
PID & \num{-16.296}\\
White & \num{1.555}\\
Female & \num{-2.100}\\
Education & \num{-3.890}\\
Age & \num{-1.858}\\
Employed & \num{-0.839}\\
Constant & \num{12.031}\\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{\rule{0pt}{1em}Two-way T-Test of point estimates.}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: It will really depend on the contents of `file_1.tex`.  If it has a `\labelthistable` command in it, then your approach might work.

Comment: Gotcha. I've updated my question to include an example of the contents of an input file.

Comment: `\AddToHookNext{env/tabular/before}{\label{tab:file_1_table}}`  should work (if you have a current latex).

Comment: why don't you have `\label` already in the files? that is the simplest solution and provides the most readable source code.